# Elastic search query results in exception Illegal pattern component: p

Tags: datetime, elasticsearch, jodatime

I have an index where `dataField` is defined as:

```
"ts":{"type":"date","format":"strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"}
```

When I try to do a `rangeQuery` using:

```
gte=1522871220000, lte=1522881220000
```

with format

```
DateTime.parse(source.get("ts").get.asInstanceOf[String],
               DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"))
```

I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: p
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.parsePatternTo(DateTimeFormat.java:566)
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.createFormatterForPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:687)
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:177)

When I do `curl` query to search on my index I see:

```
"ts" : "2018-04-05T01:18:15.218Z"
```

Why do I get this exception?

Comment: What is  version of JodaTime you are using?

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs in the `forPattern` method, so the code that *should* be causing this is:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
```

But this doesn't throw any exception. The only way I could get the same exception is when I put a `p` in the pattern string:

```
// this throws the same exception you've got
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("pyyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
                           ^
```

That's because `p` is not one of the allowed letters in a pattern - see the javadoc for more info: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html

Anyway, I have some guesses:

- this is not the code that produces the exception
- there might be some other formatter being created somewhere else, either by you, or by the API's you're using (and it's trying to create a formatter with `p` in the pattern)